# How to fix automatically redirection in netlify page

Tags: heroku, netlify

The url has been refreshed on the netlify page. This will automatically redirect to the api server url, not the netlify url.

In the `_redirects` file, I changed the http status from 301 to something else, but the results were the same.

Below is my `_redirects` file.

```
/* https://api.herokuapp.com/:splat 301
```

I want to solve the redirection problem quickly. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Where is your redirects file placed? What is your netlify url?

Comment: The _redirects file is in public. netlify url is: https://training-front.netlify.com/

Comment: Select BlogPost from the menu. The api server receives the data but does not display it on the screen. Try refreshing. It will be redirected to api server url.

Comment: Hey, my korean isn't good :D But I've noticed this: It says "#/blog/:id/1/" in one of the blog items as URL - I assume the placeholder :id isn't replaced as expected. With this comes that URL is "blog/undefined/1" - not sure what the reasons behind these are, but I would continue researching in this direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `redirects` file must be in the`build` directory. And since it builds as a web page reflecting the build status, it needs to be put into the repository with the built state due to the nature of netlify.